# How to detect Alt + left key in ToolStripTextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In C# - WinForms, how to detect Alt + left key when it is pressed in ToolStripTextBox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
        if (this.ActiveControl == toolStripTextBox1.Control && keyData == (Keys.Alt | Keys.Left)) {
            MessageBox.Show("it's special");
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried overriding ProcessCmdKey for ToolStripBox, but it didn't work and using KeyPreview for Form, but haven't thought about this.